# how to use cookie in laravel 5.4 to store data

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5

i am creating a website which needs to store user info and save to cookie.
here is my get cookie controller

```
public function index($id, Request $request)
{    
    $petitions = Petitions::where('id',$id)->first();
    $sign->name  = $request->cookie('name'); 
    $sign->email = $request->cookie('email');

    return view('petitions.index', compact('petitions'))->with(['name'=>$sign->name,'email'=>$sign->email]);
}
```

and here is set cookie controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $sign = new ActionUsers();

    $sign->name = $request->get('name');
    $sign->email = $request->get('email');
    $sign->job = $request->get('job');
    $sign->reason = $request->get('reason');
    $sign->ip_address = $request->get('ip_address');
    $sign->petition_id = $request->get('petition_id');
    $sign->is_anonymous = $request->get('is_anonymous');

    $sign->save(); 

    $name_cookie = cookie('name', $sign->name, 30);
    $email_cookie = cookie('email', $sign->email, 30);

    return back()->withCookie($name_cookie,$email_cookie);
}
```

my view to check cookie existed

```
@if( isset($sign->name)  &&  isset($sign->email) )
    done!
@else Oops! Error
```

and return error Creating default object from empty value in  $sign->name  = $request->cookie('name'); 
    $sign->email = $request->cookie('email');

anyone help me solve that! thank you

Comment: I don't see `$sign` initialize in index function.

Comment: ohhh i got it, but i want get cookie. Can u have an idea for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try return in store function as :

`return back()->withCookie($name_cookie)->withCookie($email_cookie);`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

```
$response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response(view('your_view'));
$response->withCookie(cookie('cookieName' , 'cookieValue' , expires_in_minutes));
return $response;
```

or

```
\Cookie::queue('cookieName', 'cookieValue', expires_in_minutes);
return view('your_view');
```

you can also use this code to get cookies :

```
$request->cookie('coockieName');
```